# PhoneNumber Formatter using Constructor functions JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript, and I have this problem where I have to convert an array of numbers [6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2] and

**return as a string in this format: (650) 835-9172.** using all the functions in this structure

```js
function PhoneNumberFormatter(numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers;
}

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
  var string = '';
  string = getAreaCode()+getExchangeCode()+"-"+getLineNumber()    //I did this
 
  return string;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
 let areaCode = this.numbers.slice(0,3);            //I did this
 return parenthesize(areaCode)                      //I did this

};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getExchangeCode = function() {
  return this.numbers.slice(3,6);     //I did this
 
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getLineNumber = function() {
  return this.numbers.slice(6,10);     //I did this
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.parenthesize = function(string) {
  return '(' + string + ')';
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice = function(start, end) {
  return this.numbers.slice(start, end).join('');
};
```

Some help please?

Comment: You need to use `this.` to address methods on the current object

Comment: In this way?

```PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
  var string = '';
  string = this.getAreaCode()+this.getExchangeCode()+"-"+this.getLineNumber()
  console.log(string)
  return string;
};```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgot to use this keyword for the functions prototype methods. In each prototype method you have taken the sliced elements as strings without joining the elements.

Here is your code:-

```js
function PhoneNumberFormatter(numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers;
}

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
  var string = '';
  string = this.getAreaCode()+this.getExchangeCode()+"-"+this.getLineNumber()    //I did this
 
  return string;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
 let areaCode = this.slice(0,3);//I did this
 return this.parenthesize(areaCode)                      //I did this

};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getExchangeCode = function() {
  return this.slice(3,6);     //I did this
 
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getLineNumber = function() {
  return this.slice(6,10);     //I did this
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.parenthesize = function(string) {
  return '(' + string + ')';
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice = function(start, end) {
  return this.numbers.slice(start, end).join('');
};

console.log(new PhoneNumberFormatter([6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2]).render())
```

Comment: Ohhhh...! I see, Thank you so much Saddam!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have edited your snippet here. I am leaving it to you to figure out how to use join correctly for your formatting requirements, plus how to add the space after the area code.

```js
function PhoneNumberFormatter(numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers;
}

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
  var string = '';
  string = this.getAreaCode()+this.getExchangeCode()+"-"+this.getLineNumber()    //I did this
 
  return string;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
 let areaCode = this.numbers.slice(0,3);            //I did this
 return this.parenthesize(areaCode)                      //I did this

};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getExchangeCode = function() {
  return this.numbers.slice(3,6);     //I did this
 
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getLineNumber = function() {
  return this.numbers.slice(6,10);     //I did this
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.parenthesize = function(string) {
  return '(' + string + ')';
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice = function(start, end) {
  return this.numbers.slice(start, end).join('');
};

var pnf = new PhoneNumberFormatter([6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2]);
console.log(pnf.render());
```

Comment: Your code gives this output: `"6,5,0"8,3,5-9,1,7,2`. OP stated requirement was to `return as a string in this format: (650) 835-9172`

Comment: @maksymiuk sorry it wasn't meant to be published yet

Comment: So the ```this.number.slice(x,x)``` is not the same as call the function ```PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice``` ?

Comment: @Karim these are two different functions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way using the [Javascript Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Also some of your method calls were missing the `this` keyword, but others have already pointed that out.

```js
function PhoneNumberFormatter(numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers;
}

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
  return `${this.getAreaCode()} ${this.getExchangeCode()}-${this.getLineNumber()}`;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
 return `(${this.numbers[0]}${this.numbers[1]}${this.numbers[2]})`;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getExchangeCode = function() {
  return `${this.numbers[3]}${this.numbers[4]}${this.numbers[5]}`;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getLineNumber = function() {
  return `${this.numbers[6]}${this.numbers[7]}${this.numbers[8]}${this.numbers[9]}`;    
};
var pnf = new PhoneNumberFormatter([6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2]);
console.log(pnf.render());
```